# bootstrap-3 change transition-property on navbar collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could anybody, please, explain how to change the transition-property of the collapsing element in a standard bootstrap-3 navbar? I want the transition to be something like this, but with the 'top' property when clicked on the hamburger menu: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this following example i made here:
http://jsfiddle.net/f5jzo25t/

I used css3 ':target' that worked well with 'a' elements.

```
img:target {
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

You can read more about it:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Hope that will help you

Comment: Thank you! But what I meant was how to implement this into bootstrap, because it seems to have it's own javascript code for the collapsing element and I'm having problems with understanding it.

Comment: I found this:https://www.bootply.com/dragan/3AZB0lGFyt. Maybe that will help you, in this example you have only bootstrap with jquery.

Comment: Seems to be not it again. I think it has something to do with the .collapsing class. But when I change it, it doesn't work for some reason.
`.navbar-collapse.collapsing
{
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  overflow: hidden;
     transition-property: top;
     transition-duration: 0.1s;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
}`